# How to get json string from output field value in visualforce?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get a json string variable in my javascript by accessing the value in an output field. The basic setup looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var previousOnload = window.onload; window.onload = function() { if (previousOnload) { previousOnload(); } doStuff(); }

     function doStuff() {

        var myObj = document.getElementById("jsonStr").value

        for( k in myObj.study ){
            document.getElementById(k).value = myObj.study[k];
            }
        }
    </script>

<div ><apex:outputText value="{!StudyJSON}" id="jsonStr"/></div>
```

On the screen the outputText is shown as

```
{"study":{"moleculeDescription":"RONTALIZUMAB","protocolTitle":"IMM","protocolNumber":"GA00806","studyName":"Interferon alpha in SLE Phase II LCM Option","therapeuticArea":"INFLAMMATORY,AUTOIMMUNE&BONE","startDate":"2009-03-25","endDate":"2013-08-22"}}
```

which is exactly what I want my variable to equal. I've also tried to access it like this (see below), but it comes back as undefined.

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.jsonStr}').value)
```

What is the proper way to set var myObj = to the json string in the outputText field? Thanks much for any help on this!

Comment: Try using JSON.parse() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I solved it, javascript accepts formulas from the salesforce apex controller, so all had to do was set myObj = {!StudyJSON}